# How to specialize functions of template of template?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, partial-specialization

How to override functions of specialization of template of template?

I'm building a c++11 matrix out of vectors of vectors.  I already implemented the vectors (can't use `std::vector`) and I want the matrix to inherit from `myVector<myVector<T>>`.  `myVector<T>` works fine, but `myVector<myVector<T>>` has some functions I want to override (to delete them).  How can I do that?

code:

```
template <typename T> class myMatrix : public myVector<myVector<T>>{
 ...
 //scalar multiplication
 myVector<T> MyVector<T>::operator*(const T& scalar) const{...}
}
```

I want to delete `operator*` function only from `myVector<myVector<T>>` specialization (so that `myVector<int>` instances will be able to use function, but `myVector<myVector<int>>` instances will not).

Comment: Use aggregation instead.

Comment: A matrix is **not** a `vector<vector<T>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using delete?

```
class A
{
    public:
    A(){;};
    int some_function();
};

class B: public A
{
    public:
    B():A(){;};
    int some_function() = delete;
};
```

Comment: Ok. I see. Could you test to delete the virtual word?

Comment: If both `virtual` are removed, yes, it works [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/820ebb22b61cf52c).

Comment: The problem is that you can always invoke the base implementation:

    B t;
    t.A::some_function()

but with very explicit syntax. It's ok for you?

Answer (score 0):

This solution isn't completely generic but works for a specific data type:

```
template <class T>
class Vector {

public:

    virtual void DoSomething () {
        printf("general Vector template");
    }

};

template<>
class Vector <Vector<int>> {
public:

 void DoSomething () = delete;


};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Vector<int> iv;
    iv.DoSomething();  // OK;

    Vector<Vector<int>> viv;
    viv.DoSomething(); // ERROR: attempt to use a deleted function;

    return 0;
}
```